# Maximum trace of powers of symmetric $\{0,1\}$-valued matrix with fixed row and column sums

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, combinatorial-optimization

Maximize $\operatorname{tr}(A^k)$ over binary symmetric $n$ by $n$ matrices subject to $$a_{ii}=0, \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}=d, \sum_{i=1}^na_{ij}=d,$$
where $d,k$ are fixed positive integers.

I am having trouble even for the case where $k=5$ and $d=4,$ so even some help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for an exact formula or just asymptotic behavior as $n\to \infty$? Also this is the same as maximizing the number of closed walks of lenght $k$ in a simple $d$-regular graph on $n$ vertices.

Comment: Very similar question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/420301/maximum-number-of-cycles-on-regular-graphs (The difference is cycles vs closed walks)

Comment: This question is very close (at least for $k$ large when $n$ is fixed) to asking for the largest possible second largest eigenvalue $\lambda_2$. There is a big literature on second largest eigenvalues of graphs. In particular, $\lambda_2$ can be arbitrarily close to $\lambda_1=d$ according to the answer of LeechLattice at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/333361.